# Question Involving Dot/Cross Products

Tags: cross-product

Let A, B, and C be vectors in $R^3$. Let $ A = 2B - C, B\bullet C = 2, |A \times C| = 1, and |C| = 3.$ Find $|A| and |B|$. So far, I know that $A\bullet C = 2B\bullet C - C\bullet C$, so $A\bullet C = 2(2) - 9 = -5$ but I'm a little lost on how to approach this next

Comment: $A\cdot C=\lvert A\rvert\,\lvert C\rvert\cos\theta$ and $\lvert A\times C\rvert=\lvert A\rvert\,\lvert C\rvert\lvert\sin\theta\rvert$. Do you think that you can make use of that?

Comment: Incidentally, use `\cdot` for the dot product, not `\bullet`.

Comment: I think so. So $(A\cdot C)^2$ = $|A|^2|C|^2 cos^2$ and $(A\times C)^2$ =  $|A|^2|C|^2sin^2$ so if I add them together I can simplify $cos^2 + sin^2 = 1$ but I'm still confused because one of them is the magnitude of the cross product but the other is just the dot product

Comment: You know the values of $A\cdot C$, $\lvert A\times C\lvert$ and $\lvert C\rvert$, so you ought to be able solve the resulting equation for $\lvert A\rvert$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have an idea of what to do now. Does $|sin\theta|^2$ = $sin\theta^2$ or are they different? I think they should be the same because it's just a constant

Comment: Is the square of any number at all equal to the square of its absolute value?

Comment: I thought the | | was the symbol for magnitude, not absolute value

Comment: And the magnitude of a scalar is...?

Comment: Oh true just the scalar itself, thanks!